# Qt linking error with the signals, LNK2019

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a Qt program.
I created a signal like this:

```
signals:
    void updateBarSignal(int);
```

It works well.
Then I add the second signal

```
signals:
    void updateBarSignal(int);
    void processImgThreadFinishSignal();
```

The Visual Studio hinted me that the `processImgThreadFinishSignal` has no definition, so I tried to build the code but there is an linking error
from `processImgThreadFinishSignal`.
It seems that the compiler doesn't regard `processImgThreadFinishSignal` as as a signal like `updateBarSignal`, it's weird.

Comment: its a bug,  you don't need define the processImgThreadFinishSignal.

Comment: How are you building your Qt program?  Are you using qmake/cmake?  It looks to me like the meta-object compiler (moc) is not being run automatically.

Comment: do you at any point `call` `processImgThreadFinishSignal` as if it were a function?

Comment: You need to execute `qmake`. In some cases you need also to add `#include "main.moc"` for example if your class is in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Thank everyone .I have solved this problem, the signals should be connected to slots.

Answer (score 0):

sword blade:

> I have solved this problem, the signals should be connected to slots.